# UICollectionView first cell is loading larger than the rest on tvOS

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, focus, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

So I have a UICollectionView, I have made it so that when the focus changes to a new cell the image in the cell expands. For some reason though whenever the UICollectionView loads the first cell is larger than the rest of the cells (see screenshot below). How can I stop it from doing this?

[image]

My code for the changing off the image on focus is:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didUpdateFocusInContext:(UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext *)context withAnimationCoordinator:(UIFocusAnimationCoordinator *)coordinator {

    NSIndexPath *previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath;

    TrophyCollectionViewCell *previousCell = (TrophyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:previousIndexPath];
    TrophyCollectionViewCell *cell = (TrophyCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        if (previousCell.trophyImageView != nil) {
            previousCell.trophyImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        if (cell.trophyImageView != nil) {
            cell.trophyImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
        }

        if (previousCell.resetImageView != nil) {
            previousCell.resetImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        }

        if (cell.resetImageView != nil) {
            cell.resetImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
        }

    }];

}
```

Other than this I have no other code affecting the size of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by just setting `CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);` for the previously focused and next focused cells in the `didUpdateFocusInContext` method.

Answer (score 0):

The Focus Manager looks for the first focusable element starting from the top left corner of the screen, so that bigger element is probably the one which received the focus.

It might be bigger because of the having the property adjusts​Image​When​Ancestor​Focused set to true.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview/1627692-adjustsimagewhenancestorfocused